# CSS :not Function Not Working

Tags: css

I have a problem with css **:not** function.

When I hovering to link there is underline both of them Item1 & Description. I don't want to see underline below Description when hover.

Here is my menu code:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="#">
     Item 1
     <span>Description</span>
    </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
span { display:block; }
ul li a:hover:not(span) { color:blue; text-decoration: underline; }
```

When I change span display to inline-block it is working nice but need to be only block. How can I solve it ?

Also, Inline-block shows the description NEAR of the Item. I want to put it under of the Item Name. How can I make it ?

Comment: you are saying to the style a:not(span), A that is not a SPAN, of course a isn't a span ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are saying to the style a:not(span), A that is not a SPAN, of course a isn't a span ;)

Use a css class for this purpose for instance like :

```css
span { display:block; }
ul li a:not(.has-span):hover { color:red; text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="#">
     Item 1
     <span>Description</span>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#" class="has-span">
     Item 2
     <span>Description</span>
    </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any explanation?

Comment: Said in comment of the question

Comment: Thank you, I gave another class to Item Name and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put your state (`:hover`) before the selector. So you need to change it to:

```
ul li a:not(span):hover { color:blue; text-decoration: underline; }
```

And moreover this will **not** work, because, a single element cannot be a `<a>` as well as a `<span>`. Instead you need to just use:

```css
span { display:block; }
ul li a:hover { color:blue; text-decoration: underline; }
ul li a:hover span { color:black; text-decoration: none; }
```